# Building access matrix based on parent=>child relationship of objects?

Tags: php, mysql, matrix, parent-child, access-control

Some background:

A `game` belongs to a `round`,
A `round` belongs to a `season`,
A `season` belongs to a `competition`
A `competition` is unowned.

We have eight tables

**name => columns**

```
`games`            => `id`, `round_id`,  
`rounds`           => `id`, `season_id`,  
`seasons`          => `id`, `competition_id`,  
`competitions`      => `id`,
----
`user_game`        => `user_id`, `game_id`, 
`user_round`       => `user_id`, `round_id`,
`user_season`      => `user_id`, `season_id`,
`user_competition` => `user_id`, `competition_id`
```

So, the first four tables link the different parts together,
the second four tables link a user to the respective part.

Some dummy data, note I've split the tables when the second id changes for easy reading.

**First four tables**

```
/--GAMES--------------\      /--ROUNDS-------------\
| id | round_id       |      | id | season_id      |
| 1  | 1              |      | 1  | 1              |
| 2  | 1              |      | 2  | 1              |
|----|----------------|      | 3  | 1              |
| 3  | 2              |      |----|----------------|
| 4  | 2              |      | 4  | 2              |
|----|----------------|      | 5  | 2              |
| 5  | 3              |      | 6  | 2              |
| 6  | 3              |      |----|----------------|
|----|----------------|      | 7  | 3              |
| 7  | 4              |      | 8  | 3              |
| 8  | 4              |      | 9  | 3              |
|----|----------------|      |----|----------------|
| 9  | 5              |      | 10 | 4              |
| 10 | 5              |      \---------------------/
|----|----------------|
| 11 | 6              |      /--SEASONS------------\
| 12 | 6              |      | id | competition_id |
|----|----------------|      | 1  | 1              |
| 13 | 7              |      | 2  | 1              |
| 14 | 7              |      |----|----------------|
|----|----------------|      | 3  | 2              |
| 15 | 8              |      | 4  | 2              |
| 16 | 8              |      \---------------------/
|----|----------------|
| 17 | 9              |      /--COMPETITIONS-------\
| 18 | 9              |      | id                  |
|----|----------------|      | 1                   |
| 19 | 10             |      | 2                   |
| 20 | 10             |      \---------------------/
\---------------------/
```

**The next four tables are best explained in the list below**

Users:

- **User 1**

  - linked to just game 1: 
    `user_game (user_id:1, game_id:1)`
  - has `direct` access on game 1
  - has `parent` access on round 1
  - has `parent` access on season 1
  - has `parent` access on competition 1
- **User 2**

  - linked to just round 1: 
    `user_round (user_id:2, round_id:1)`
  - has `child` access on games 1,2
  - has `direct` access on round 1
  - has `parent` access on season 1
  - has `parent` access on competition 1
- **User 3**

  - linked to round 1: 
    `user_round (user_id:3, round_id:1)`
  - has all of **user 2**'s access
  - linked to game 2: 
    `user_game (user_id:3, game_id:2).
  - has `direct` access on game 2
  - also linked to game 13: 
    `user_game (user_id:3, game_id:13)`
  - has `direct` access on game 13
  - has `parent` access on round 7
  - has `parent` access on season 3
  - has `parent` access on competition 2

So, when fetching access for the three users above I want to end up with these three arrays,
Noting that:
`parent_access`: User has partial access as has access to a child object (regardless of what object)
`direct_access`: User has full access as has been granted directly
`child access`: User has full access as a parent object (regardless of what object) has been granted direct access

**User 1**

```
$user1 = array(
    'games' => array(
        [1] => array(
            'id' => 1,
            'parent_access' => false,
            'direct_access' => true,
            'child_access'  => false
        )
    ),

    'rounds' => array(
        [1] => array(
            'id' => 1,
            'parent_access' => true,
            'direct_access' => false,
            'child_access'  => false
        )
    ),

    'seasons' => array(
        [1] => array(
            'id' => 1,
            'parent_access' => true,
            'direct_access' => false,
            'child_access'  => false
        ),
    ),

    'competitions' => array(
        [1] => array(
            'id' => 1,
            'parent_access' => true,
            'direct_access' => false,
            'child_access'  => false
        ),
    )
);
```

**User 2**

```
$user2 = array(
    'games' => array(
        [1] => array(
            'id' => 1,
            'parent_access' => false,
            'direct_access' => false,
            'child_access'  => true
        ),
        [2] => array(
            'id' => 2,
            'parent_access' => false,
            'direct_access' => false,
            'child_access'  => true
        )
    ),

    'rounds' => array(
        [1] => array(
            'id' => 1,
            'parent_access' => false,
            'direct_access' => true,
            'child_access'  => false
        )
    ),

    'seasons' => array(
        [1] => array(
            'id' => 1,
            'parent_access' => true,
            'direct_access' => false,
            'child_access'  => false
        ),
    ),

    'competitions' => array(
        [1] => array(
            'id' => 1,
            'parent_access' => true,
            'direct_access' => false,
            'child_access'  => false
        ),
    )
);
```

**User 3**

```
$user3 = array(
    'games' => array(
        [1] => array(
            'id' => 1,
            'parent_access' => false,
            'direct_access' => false,
            'child_access'  => true
        ),
        [2] => array(
            'id' => 2,
            'parent_access' => false,
            'direct_access' => true,
            'child_access'  => true
        ),
        [13] => array(
            'id' => 13,
            'parent_access' => false,
            'direct_access' => true,
            'child_access'  => false
        )
    ),

    'rounds' => array(
        [1] => array(
            'id' => 1,
            'parent_access' => false,
            'direct_access' => true,
            'child_access'  => false
        ),
        [7] => array(
            'id' => 7,
            'parent_access' => true,
            'direct_access' => false,
            'child_access'  => false
        )
    ),

    'seasons' => array(
        [1] => array(
            'id' => 1,
            'parent_access' => true,
            'direct_access' => false,
            'child_access'  => false
        ),
        [3] => array(
            'id' => 3,
            'parent_access' => true,
            'direct_access' => false,
            'child_access'  => false
        )
    ),

    'competitions' => array(
        [1] => array(
            'id' => 1,
            'parent_access' => true,
            'direct_access' => false,
            'child_access'  => false
        ),
        [2] => array(
            'id' => 2,
            'parent_access' => true,
            'direct_access' => false,
            'child_access'  => false
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: With regards to my attempts, anything I can come up with involves fetching every row from all eight tables, and looping over each `user_*` table and building the matrix, the for each row in those tables that is not a `user_game` row looping over all the lower objects to add the `child` access flag to that object, but my god, that is a a lot of looping! and to much code to post with my question, hence why I have not shown my attempt!

Comment: Also, look at those dummy data tables, I don't think many people can say I didn't put enough effort into my question ;)

Answer (score 0):

A bit different of an outcome, but this is posted here to show my current working, and it still does work as an answer, albeit one I am not happy with.

So, here is my current code:
lines like: `$competitions = $this->competitions->disabled(true)->getAll();` run the query on the competitions table and return a custom object, so things are a bit different there, but you should be able to work out what it does by the code.

What U don't like about this here is that we have **18 foreach loops!** many nested so that's **18 re-running foreach loops!** Can anyone see a way to reduce this?

```
public function access($user_id, $action = 'none')
{

    $access = array(
        'competitions' => array()
    );

    /* COMPETITIONS */
    $competitions = $this->competitions->disabled(true)->getAll();
    foreach ($competitions as $competition) {
        $access['competitions'][$competition->data('id')] = array(
            //'item' => $competition,
            'type' => 'competition',
            'id' => $competition->data('id'),
            'child_access' => false,
            'direct_access' => false,
            'parent_access' => false,
            'seasons' => array()
        );

        /* SEASONS */
        $seasons = $competition->seasons(true);
        foreach ($seasons as $season) {
            $access['competitions'][$competition->data('id')]['seasons'][$season->data('id')] = array(
                //'item' => $season,
                'type' => 'season',
                'id' => $season->data('id'),
                'child_access' => false,
                'direct_access' => false,
                'parent_access' => false,
                'rounds' => array()
            );

            /* ROUNDS */

            $rounds = $season->rounds(true);
            foreach ($rounds as $round) {
                $access['competitions'][$competition->data('id')]['seasons'][$season->data('id')]['rounds'][$round->data('id')] = array(
                    //'item' => $round,
                    'type' => 'round',
                    'id' => $round->data('id'),
                    'child_access' => false,
                    'direct_access' => false,
                    'parent_access' => false,
                    'games' => array()
                );

                /* GAMES */
                $games = $round->games(true);
                foreach ($games as $game) {
                    //dump('$access["competitions"]['.$competition->data('id').']["seasons"]['.$season->data('id').']["rounds"]['.$round->data('id').']["games"]['.$game->data('id').']');
                    $access['competitions'][$competition->data('id')]['seasons'][$season->data('id')]['rounds'][$round->data('id')]['games'][$game->data('id')] = array(
                        //'item' => $game,
                        'type' => 'game',
                        'id' => $game->data('id'),
                        'child_access' => false,
                        'direct_access' => false,
                        'parent_access' => false
                    );
                }

            }
        }
    }


    /* CHECK COMPETITIONS */
    $competitions = $this->db->select('competition_id')->from('user_competition')->where('user_id', $user_id)->get();
    foreach ($competitions->result() as $id) {
        $id = $id->competition_id;
        $access['competitions'][$id]['direct_access'] = true;

        /* SEASONS */
        foreach ($access['competitions'][$id]['seasons'] as &$season) {
            $season['child_access'] = true;

            /* ROUNDS */
            foreach ($season['rounds'] as &$round) {
                $round['child_access'] = true;

                /* GAMES */
                foreach ($round['games'] as &$game) {
                    $game['child_access'] = true;
                    unset($game);
                }

                unset($round);

            }
            unset($season);
        }
    }

    /* CHECK SEASONS */
    $seasons = $this->db->select('season_id')->from('user_season')->where('user_id', $user_id)->get();
    foreach ($seasons->result() as $id) {
        $id = $id->season_id;
        $competition_id = $this->seasons->disabled(true)->get($id)->data('competition id');

        $competition = $access['competitions'][$competition_id];
        $competition['parent_access'] = true;

        $season = $competition['seasons'][$id];
        $season['direct_access'] = true;

        /* ROUNDS */
        foreach ($season['rounds'] as &$round) {
            $round['child_access'] = true;

            /* GAMES */
            foreach ($round['games'] as &$game) {
                $game['child_access'] = true;
                unset($game);
            }
            unset($round);

        }
    }

    /* CHECK ROUNDS */
    $rounds = $this->db->select('round_id')->from('user_round')->where('user_id', $user_id)->get();
    foreach ($rounds->result() as $id) {
        $id = $id->round_id;
        $round_obj = $this->rounds->disabled(true)->get($id);
        $season_obj = $round_obj->season();
        $competition_id = $season_obj->data('competition id');

        $access['competitions'][$competition_id]['parent_access'] = true;

        $access['competitions'][$competition_id]['seasons'][$season_obj->data('id')]['parent_access'] = true;

        $access['competitions'][$competition_id]['seasons'][$season_obj->data('id')]['rounds'][$id]['direct_access'] = true;


        /* GAMES */

        foreach ($access['competitions'][$competition_id]['seasons'][$season_obj->data('id')]['rounds'][$id]['games'] as &$game) {
            $game['child_access'] = true;
            unset($game);
        }

    }

    /* CHECK GAMES */
    $games = $this->db->select('game_id')->from('user_game')->where('user_id', $user_id)->get();
    foreach ($games->result() as $id) {
        $id = $id->game_id;
        $game_obj = $this->games->disabled(true)->get($id);
        $round_obj = $game_obj->round();
        $season_obj = $round_obj->season();
        $competition_id = $season_obj->data('competition id');

        $access['competitions'][$competition_id]['parent_access'] = true;

        $access['competitions'][$competition_id]['seasons'][$season_obj->data('id')]['parent_access'] = true;

        $access['competitions'][$competition_id]['seasons'][$season_obj->data('id')]['rounds'][$round_obj->data('id')]['parent_access'] = true;
        $access['competitions'][$competition_id]['seasons'][$season_obj->data('id')]['rounds'][$round_obj->data('id')]['games'][$id]['direct_access'] = true;

    }

    if ($action == 'trim') {
        foreach ($access['competitions'] as $k => &$competition) {
            if ($competition['child_access'] === false &&
                $competition['direct_access'] === false &&
                $competition['parent_access'] === false
            ) {
                unset($access['competitions'][$k]);
                continue;
            }

            foreach ($competition['seasons'] as $k1 => &$season) {
                if ($season['child_access'] === false &&
                    $season['direct_access'] === false &&
                    $season['parent_access'] === false
                ) {
                    unset($competition['seasons'][$k1]);
                    continue;
                }
                foreach ($season['rounds'] as $k2 => &$round) {
                    if ($round['child_access'] === false &&
                        $round['direct_access'] === false &&
                        $round['parent_access'] === false
                    ) {
                        unset($season['rounds'][$k2]);
                        continue;
                    }

                    foreach ($round['games'] as $k3 => $game) {
                        if ($game['child_access'] === false &&
                            $game['direct_access'] === false &&
                            $game['parent_access'] === false
                        ) {
                            unset($round['games'][$k3]);
                            continue;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    dump($access);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an authorization language such as XACML to express who can access which particular data. Then, the tables you have become one source of "attributes".

With XACML you can express rules such as:

- a user can view a game if that user is taking part in that game
- a user can view a game if that user can view the round the game belongs to (parent-child relationship)...